# Incrementar variável enquanto segurar um button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Estou precisando fazer uma ação dentro de um Button, quando a pessoa pressionar e segurar com o lado esquerdo do mouse no Button, incrementar uma variável até soltar. Soltou, para à ação.

Dentro do método desse Button, quero incrementar a seguinte variável:

```
int incrementar = 0;
incrementar++;

int valor = incrementar;
```

Comment: Eu não sei c#, mas pela lógica deve ter o método que é chamado quando vc clica e quando vc solta um botão, no que é chamado quando vc clica, vc chama outro método que faz um while(verdadeiro), e no de soltar vc muda o valor pra falso

Comment: Eu não sei qual método é esse, testei alguns aqui, mas.. sem sucesso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coloque um `Timer` no seu form, e defina o intervalo que a variavel será incrementada enquanto estiver com o mouse pressionado.

Feito isso, você utiliza o Evento `MouseDown` do Button, para habilitar o timer, e o evento `MouseUp` para desabilitar:

```
int incremento = 0;

private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}

private void button2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    MessageBox.Show(incremento.ToString());
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    incremento++;
}
```

Comment: Era disso que eu tava falando haha, +1

Answer (score -5):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="u" value="0" />

<input type="button" id="b" value="Aperte!" />

<script>
    $(function () {
        var timer;
    
        $('#b').on('mousedown mouseup', function (e) {
            switch (e.type) {
                case 'mouseup':
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    break;
                case 'mousedown':
                    (function loop() {
                        timer = setTimeout(function () {
                            var u = +$('#u').val();
                            $('#u').val(++u);
                            loop();
                        }, 40);
                    })();
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, pensei que era JS :(